# Is there a better way to implement an inheritable method that returns an object inheriting off that class type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am trying to make a base class that specifies a method that returns, say a list of its own type. I want this method to work correctly on inheriting classes, ie. to return a list of the inherited class.

This is the only way I can think of doing it.

```
public abstract class Base<T>
  where T : Base<T>
{
  public List<T> getList()
  {
    return new List<T>();
  }
}

public class Foo : Base<Foo>
{
}

var foo = new Foo();

// Should return List<Foo>
var fooList = foo.getList();
```

Is there a better way that does not require `Foo` to inherit off of a base with itself as a type? Say specifying `List<this>` or similar in `Base`?

As Groo points out, ideally I do not want `class Bar : Base<Foo>` to be possible.

**ACTUAL PROBLEM I'M TRYING TO SOLVE UPDATE:**

Basically, I'm trying to get Entity Framework code-first POCO classes to return their own model stores so that I can write code that handles the POCO classes generically in terms of their validation, and saving for an API.

Model stores encapsulate basic CRUD operations so that we can override the access methods to do additional things like hiding soft-deleted items.

I decided to do this after I implemented the same `getModelStore` method both in the validation class, and in the DTO code (data transfer object - translates between WSDL API  and POCO).

```
public abstract class EntityBase<T>
  where T : EntityBase<T>
{
  public abstract ModelStore<T> getModelStore(Repository repository);
}

public class Foo : EntityBase<Foo>
{
  public override ModelStore<Foo> getModelStore(Repository repository);
  {
    // repository.Foo is a Foo ModelStore
    return repository.Foo;
  }
}

var repo = new Repository();
var foo = new Foo();

// Should return the ModelStore for Foo
var fooList = foo.getModelStore(repo);
```

Comment: The problem is that nothing prevents you from writing `class Bar : Base<Foo>`.

Comment: Why do you want base class, when this base class would be almost impossible to use by itself? Eg. Whats the point of abstraction, when this abstraction is not used?

Comment: @Euphoric: code reuse? How would you use an actual `abstract` class "by itself"?

Comment: @Groo Can you be more specific? Reuse what? Reuse where?

Comment: I have made the base abstract. Only reason I didn't initially is because I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible.

Comment: Gustav, why do you want to force class's method to return itself? To me, that requirement itself seems weird.

Comment: Can you use static method `public static List<T> GetList<T>(T item) where T : Base {return new List<T>();}`
and then just use
`var fooList = Base.GetList(new Foo());`
is that good solution for you?

Comment: @Euphoric: the weird requirement is known as the (curiously named) ["Curiously recurring template pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), so it's not that uncommon. [Eric Lippert also wrote about it in his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx). Regarding the code reuse? If you ever created an abstract class, you did it to reuse code in several base classes (otherwise, you should have used an interface because multiple inheritance is impossible in C#). I am not sure what you're asking?

Comment: @py3r3str: OP wants to have the returning generic parameter tied to the instance type.

Comment: @Gustav: You might want to add a more descriptive example, because there might be other ways to achieve what you are looking for in your specific case. I presume you are not simply creating an empty list?

Comment: What is a model store supposed to do? Does that contain CRUD repository methods for a single entity?

Comment: @Groo Yes, exactly that.

Comment: The type constraint you desire cannot actually be expressed in the .net type system. There is no requirement that the system support all possible constraints. I would take a step back and look at whether your system actually needs the level of genericity you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the main problem is that these methods don't belong to actual entities, but should be provided by your repository service locator instead (well, it doesn't have to be a locator at all, ideally you would just have a composition root and inject all repo dependencies through constructors).

But the idea is to have a common base repo interface for crud operations:

```
public interface IRepo<T>
{
    T Get(long id);
    IList<T> GetAll();
    void Save(T instance);
    ... 
}
```

And specific interfaces for specific entities:

```
public interface IFooRepo : IRepo<Foo>
{
    // additional Foo-specific stuff, if needed
}
```

This allows you to have a common base abstract implementation:

```
public abstract class BaseRepo<T> : IRepo<T>
{
    // provide default implementations for Load, Save and common stuff
}
```

And then your specific repositories inherit the base class and optionally implement specific methods (note that this class shouldn't be instantiated directly anywhere, but through a DI container instead):

```
class FooRepo : BaseRepo<Foo>, IFooRepo
{
    // no need to re-implement anything except Foo-specific stuff
}
```

And finally you have your service locator (disclaimer: it's often used as a singleton but it shouldn't actually be):

```
// get the service locator
var repoFactory = GetRepoFactory();

// get the actual repo through DI
var repo = repoFactory.GetRepo<IFooRepo>();

// do stuff
var foo = repo.FindAll();
```

So, my primary remark is that the `GetRepo` method in my last code snippet doesn't belong to a POCO entity. [This article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) shows an example of a repository pattern with EF (skip to the "Implement a Generic Repository and a Unit of Work Class" part), although I would prefer the repo to be injected into the controller through DI, instead of being `new`ed inside the controller constructor.

Comment: A service locator does indeed look like a good way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to the `IList` Interface, you can define an Extension method on `Object`.
(You cannot return `List<>` or use `List` as a rawtype)

Then EVERY class throughout your whole application will serve the `MakeList` method:

Extension Method:

```
static class Class1
{
    public static IList MakeList(this Object t)
    {
        var listType = typeof(List<>);
        var finalType = listType.MakeGenericType(t.GetType());
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(finalType);
        return (IList)instance;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
 Object o = new Object();
 IList list = o.MakeList();
 list.Add(new Object());
 list.Add(new Object());

 MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());

 String s = "";
 IList stringList = s.MakeList();
 stringList.Add("hello");
 stringList.Add("world");

 MessageBox.Show(stringList.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: There are a couple problems with this answer, IMHO: 1) OP wants to create a strongly typed list, otherwise his method would just be `public IList getList()` and he wouldn't need generics at all, 2) you lose all type safety this way and can easily get runtime exceptions when trying to add objects of different types to the list, which is what OP is probably trying to avoid.

Comment: @Groo (2) You'll loose typsafety, whenever you try to produce a generic collection during runtime. Even if created dynamically, you need to ensure, that you are not adding anything *out of scope*. **real** type safety can only be provided when the type is known during design time. In any other case you would need to catch (and handle) invalid types - which you also can do with the implementation suggested. (Okay, C# has no Type-Erasure, so it's somewhat ahead the curve compared to Java.)