# Allow derived type cast as parent type to return `object`, but using the derived type's method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Given the following code (which I know won't compile and isn't correct):

```
public abstract class Fetcher {
   public abstract IEnumerable<object> Fetch();
}

public class Fetcher<T> : Fetcher {
   private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>> _fetcher;
   public Fetcher(Func<IEnumerable<T>> fetcher) { _fetcher = fetcher; }
   public IEnumerable<T> Fetch() => _fetcher(); // override or new
}
```

And this example setup:

```
var myFetchers = new List<Fetcher> {
   new Fetcher<string>(() => new List<string> { "white", "black" })),
   new Fetcher<int>(() => new List<int> { 1, 2 }))
};
```

How can I structure my code so that this will work?

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> fetcherResults =
   myFetchers.Select(fetcher => fetcher.Fetch()); // get objects from derived method
```

**TLDR;** I've thought about this a little more. A different way to state my question is: how do I run the `Fetch` method on all the items in the `myFetchers` list and save a collection of their results, without having to determine the base type of each item and do a cast to that type, while not returning `IEnumerable<object>` from the `Fetch` method itself?

The key here is that at the time the objects of different generic type are in a collection of the parent type, I want to run the derived type's method, but return the result as `IEnumerable<object>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. (This can be done using a different method if necessary, I suppose, though it would be nice if it were the same name.) This is so that a section of the code that doesn't need to know about fetchers can have its data (and just be passed `fetcherResults`), but the part of the code that does care about fetchers can completely ignore what type of data the fetchers work with (not its concern, only the consumer of the data needs to work with the specific types).

I don't have to use inheritance here, and interface `IFetcher` would work just as well. I keep thinking about how explicit interface implementation might help, but I'm just not closing the loop right now how to make this work for me:

```
// in a class implementing ICollection<T>
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _collection.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable) _collection).GetEnumerator();
```

As usual, the real situation is more complicated than this (such as the data the fetchers are providing coming from a database, etc.). But getting this one part down will be all I need.

I have looked at the following resources to no avail: [implement an inheritable method that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862020/is-there-a-better-way-to-implement-an-inheritable-method-that-returns-an-object), [call method on generic type from abstract parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128002/calling-a-method-on-a-list-of-generic-type-from-abstract-parent-class).

Comment: Why not have `IEnumerable<T> FetchGeneric()` and `IEnumerable<object> Fetch()` that simply invokes `FetchGeneric().Cast<object>()`?

Comment: I guess I was thrown off by wanting them to be the same name. It seems super obvious now that you mention that. But if I did decide to defer fetching until later when using a derived type, it sure would be nice to be able to get the specific type using the same method name.

Comment: I've updated my question, see the new paragraph starting TLDR;

Comment: What do you mean by "while no returning IEnumerable<object> from the Fetch method itself"?

Comment: If the signature of `Fetch` were `public IEnumerable<object> Fetch()` then everything would be easy. But I want it to be `public IEnumerable<T> Fetch()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a straight-forward way to do this with explicit implementation as you suspected.  This is only available if you use an interface rather than an abstract class.

```
public interface IFetcher {
    IEnumerable<object> Fetch();
}

public class Fetcher<T> : IFetcher  {
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>> _fetcher;
    public Fetcher(Func<IEnumerable<T>> fetcher) { _fetcher = fetcher; }
    IEnumerable<object> IFetcher.Fetch() => Fetch().Cast<object>();
    public IEnumerable<T> Fetch() => _fetcher();
}
```

In this implementation, the interface version of the call returns `IEnumerable<object>`, while the class-accessible version returns the more specific `IEnumerable<T>`.  If you call the fetcher through the interface, it will resolve to the first.  Calling through the class will resolve to the second.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. Why couldn't I see it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, then you can solve the problem by making `Fetcher<T>` implement a generic interface `IFetcher<T>` like this:

```
public interface IFetcher<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Fetch();
}

public class Fetcher<T> : IFetcher<T>
{
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>> _fetcher;
    public Fetcher(Func<IEnumerable<T>> fetcher) { _fetcher = fetcher; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Fetch() => _fetcher();
}
```

And then creating an adapter that can convert `IFetcher<TFrom>` to an `IFetcher<TTo>` like this:

```
public class Adaptor<TFrom, TTo> : IFetcher<TTo>
{
    private readonly IFetcher<TFrom> _fetcher;

    public Adaptor(IFetcher<TFrom> fetcher)
    {
        _fetcher = fetcher;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TTo> Fetch()
    {
        return _fetcher.Fetch().Cast<TTo>();
    }
}
```

This allows for example to convert from `IFetcher<string>` to `IFetcher<object>`.

With the help of this extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Converter<TFrom> Convert<TFrom>(this IFetcher<TFrom> fetcher)
    {
        return new Converter<TFrom>(fetcher);
    }

    public class Converter<TFrom>
    {
        private readonly IFetcher<TFrom> _fetcher;

        public Converter(IFetcher<TFrom> fetcher)
        {
            _fetcher = fetcher;
        }

        public IFetcher<TTo> To<TTo>()
        {
            return new Adaptor<TFrom, TTo>(_fetcher);
        }
    }
}
```

You can do something like this easily:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myFetchers = new List<IFetcher<object>>
    {
       new Fetcher<string>(() => new List<string> { "white", "black" }).Convert().To<object>(),
       new Fetcher<int>(() => new List<int> { 1, 2 }).Convert().To<object>()
    };

    var results = myFetchers.Select(x => x.Fetch());
}
```

Please note that you can do without the extension method, but it will make your code more readable.

Comment: I get it. You're saying to wrap Fetcher with another indirection later that takes an underlying Fetcher and then implements the object-returning interface, so that later when we `Fetch` we run the correct method but it gets converted to the object type we want. You're letting the compiler infer the type and then store that knowledge in a wrapper. I'll have to think about this, it's useful for sure, but not sure if it's the route I want to go down.